# Does drools work well on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, drools

For those who integrated drools on GAE, can you please give some feedback on

- the memory consumption (does it work with a F1 instance)?
- startup time (initialization of KnowledgeBase)
- do you serialize your KnowledgeBase objects to datastore?
- do they fit in 1MB blobs?

And more generally, I'd like to know if it's a good idea to use drools on gae

Comment: This should be asked on the Drools user list `rules-users@lists.jboss.org`.

Comment: The user group doesn't seam to be dynamic, maybe only a few people use BPM generally (since it requires complex processes) so even less are on GAE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools seems to run on GAE with some modifications as described here: https://code.google.com/p/red-piranha/wiki/ModifyDroolsRunInGoogleAppEngine#Modifications_to_allow_Drools_to_run_in_Google_App_Engine

For the statefulSession persistence, JPA seams to do the job but http://blog.athico.com/2013/05/creating-your-own-drools-and-jbpm.html explains the structure if I'll ever need to adapt (optimize for reading).

Finally, KnowledgeBase is serializable and can be saved as a blob in a desperate solution.